# search_query - check the order of queries

Tags: python

Below is my code. I'm trying to find all queries that appear in my pages. But I can't find a solution to check if they appear in the same order as in specified query. Any solutions?

```
def search_query(query, pages):

    if len(query) > 10:
        return 
    if len(pages) > 1000:
        return 

    valid_pages = 0

    for p in pages:
        valid_query = 0
    for q in query:
        if q in p:
            valid_query += 1
    if valid_query == len(query):
        valid_pages += 1
print valid_pages 

query = ["the","new","store"]
pages = ["the new store is in san francisco",
"the boy enters a new and cool store",
"this boy enters a new store",
"The new store is in the city",
"the newstore is a brand",
"there is newton in the store"]
```

Result is 5. It's ok, but if I want to check in order of query it must be 4. Thanks!

Comment: well, `'new' in 'newstore'` will always return true

Comment: you're right, but wrong result is not from this, look at this sentence  "The new store is in the city", first appears 'new', then 'store' and last is 'the', it isn't in the same order as in my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def search_query(query, pages):
    valid_pages = 0
    for p in pages:
        i = 0
        for q in query:
            j = p.find(q, i)
            if j < 0:
                break
            i = j + 1
        else:
            valid_pages += 1
    return valid_pages
```

Comment: Thanks @falsetru, I thought about comparing indexes of each query that appear to be in page, but i didn't how to do this, looks that python has a lot of secrets for me :D